# calculate relative contribution over the total in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate-functions

Hi have a df looking like:

```
keyword clicks
a       20
b       40
c       50
a       10
```

I want to obtain a grouped df that would contain something like the relative contribution of the percentage of keyword relative to the percentage of clicks.

My ultimate goal is to check whether there's a Pareto relationship 
underlying the data.

I imagine something like: 20% of keywords contribute to the 80% of clicks, to plot the result of fraction of kw vs. fraction of clicks.

Reproducible example is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'clicks': {0: 20, 1: 40, 2: 50, 3: 10},
'keyword': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'a'}})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First groupby and take the sum, and sort those values (descending, so biggest is first). Then get the cumulative percentage (in a new column) by using cumsum and dividing by the total:

```
df = df.groupby('keyword').sum().sort_values(by='clicks', ascending=False)
df['cumulative click %'] = (df['clicks'].cumsum() / sum(df['clicks']))*100
```

To get the cumulative % of keywords, reset the index (twice) to get a column that is just the row number, and divide this by the total number of rows:

```
df = df.reset_index().reset_index()
df['index'] = df['index'] + 1
df['index'] = (df['index']/len(df['index']))*100

df = df.rename(columns = {'index':'cumulative keyword %'})
```

output:

```
    cumulative keyword %    keyword clicks  cumulative click %
0   33.333333   c   50  41.666667
1   66.666667   b   40  75.000000
2   100.000000  a   30  100.000000
```

Comment: actually what's I was looking for is to express in 2 columns the relative contribution of the count of keywords to the sum of clicks: meaning x% of keywords accounts to %y of total clicks, for each level up to 100%.

Comment: Isn't that what's being shown in cumulative %? The second row is the cumulative % of 2 keywords, their contribution towards all of the clicks

Comment: Or do you also want another column with % of keywords so far? Maybe that's what I'm missing

Comment: exactly @Kewl - I was looking for the % of keywords that account for that %